# How to get name parent table by name foreign field in child table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I need to write a `php` script to work with tables in `MySql` database. I know table name and I need know name parent table by name foreign field in this child table. How can I do it with `SQL` query?

UPDATE

```
SELECT referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
WHERE table_name = '[child_table_name]'
AND column_name = '[foreign_key_field_name]'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select referenced_table_name 
from information_schema.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS 
where  table_name ='[child_table_name]' 
 --and constraint_name ='[foreign_key_constraint_name]'
```

UPDATE

```
select referenced_table_name,
referenced_column_name 
from information_schema.key_column_usage where table_name ='[child_table_name]' 
and column_name='[foreign_key_constraint_name]';
```